# Optano.Modeling not working with MipCL

Tags: c#, linear-programming

I just starting to test the optano.modeling library and I created a new console application with the packages:

- Optano.Modeling
- Optano.Modeling.Gurobi

I copied the default program showed in Optano page (http://docs.optano.net/modeling/current/userDoc/getting_started/step_install_primer.html) and everything works flawless.

This is the program.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization;
using OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.Enums;
using OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.Solver.Gurobi80;

namespace optanodemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var scope = new ModelScope())
            {
                var model = new Model();
                var x = new Variable("x");
                var y = new Variable("y");
                model.AddConstraint(x + y >= 120);
                model.AddObjective(new Objective(2*x + 3*y));

                using (var solver = new GurobiSolver())
                {
                    var solution = solver.Solve(model);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that I decided to change the solver (because I don't want to pay the Gurobi right now) to MipCL 1.41, leaving the code like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization;
using OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.Enums;
using OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.Solver.MipCL141;

namespace optanodemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var scope = new ModelScope())
            {
                var model = new Model();
                var x = new Variable("x");
                var y = new Variable("y");
                model.AddConstraint(x + y >= 120);
                model.AddObjective(new Objective(2*x + 3*y));

                using (var solver = new MipCLSolver())
                {
                    var solution = solver.Solve(model);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles but when I run it, I received the exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 
'OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.Solver.MipCL141.WrapperCsharp.MipCL141WrapperCppPINVOKE' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'MipCL141WrapperCpp': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.Solver.MipCL141.WrapperCsharp.MipCL141WrapperCppPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper.SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_MipCL141WrapperCpp(ExceptionDelegate applicationDelegate, ExceptionDelegate arithmeticDelegate, ExceptionDelegate divideByZeroDelegate, ExceptionDelegate indexOutOfRangeDelegate, ExceptionDelegate invalidCastDelegate, ExceptionDelegate invalidOperationDelegate, ExceptionDelegate ioDelegate, ExceptionDelegate nullReferenceDelegate, ExceptionDelegate outOfMemoryDelegate, ExceptionDelegate overflowDelegate, ExceptionDelegate systemExceptionDelegate)
   at OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.Solver.MipCL141.WrapperCsharp.MipCL141WrapperCppPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.Solver.MipCL141.WrapperCsharp.MipCL141WrapperCppPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper..ctor()
   at OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.Solver.MipCL141.WrapperCsharp.MipCL141WrapperCppPINVOKE..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.Solver.MipCL141.WrapperCsharp.MipCL141WrapperCppPINVOKE.new_CMIP__SWIG_0()
   at OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.Solver.MipCL141.MipCLSolver.BuildSolverModelAdapterSpecific(Int32 prioLevel)
   at OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.SolverBase.BuildConfigureAndSolveOnAdapter(Int32 prioLevel, Dictionary`2 variableValues, Boolean isResolve)
   at OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.SolverBase.SolveNonNative(Dictionary`2 variableValues, Boolean isResolve)
   at OPTANO.Modeling.Optimization.SolverBase.Solve(Model model, Dictionary`2 variableValues)
   at optanodemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Temp\test\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 21
```

After 5 hours trying to put this to work I decided to write here to see if anyone has had a similar problem.
This is what I tried:

- I checked my application folder and the file MipCL141WrapperCpp.dll is in the folder
- I downloaded the MipCL library version 1.41 from http://www.mipcl-cpp.appspot.com/download.html and I installed several times.
- I copied all the MipCL installed files to my application folder
- I set my application build to x64 instead of Any
- I dissassembled the MipCL141WrapperCpp.dll to check any other possible dependency and I saw that the code has references to mipcl.dll, VCRUNTIME140D.dll and ucrtbased.dll.  I also copied those files to my application folder.

Is there anything additional you think I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 did not install the file **ucrtbased.dll** in the windows\system32 folder.  It only installs the file **ucrtbase.dll**.

I downloaded this file from internet and added it to the application folder and everything started to work smoothly.